# execute the SSIS package from my local system into some other remote server and SSIS package is stored in the file system

Tags: ssis

I am trying to execute the SSIS package from my local system(but in my local system is not installed the Integration service software) into some other remote server and SSIS package is stored in the file system.

Now, is it possible to execute the SSIS package from C# code programmatically local system into Remote server? by using the LoadPackage method.But when I execute the SSIS package into the same server I can able to execute successfully.

Please see my below code.

```
 1. Application application = new Application();
 2. Package package = application.LoadPackage(pkgLocation, null);             
 3. DTSExecResult result = package.Execute();
```

Comment: What do you mean by "execute the package... into some other remote server"? The DTS generates a file that is stored elsewhere? You need to execute it directly on the remote server?

Answer (score 0):

No, SSIS packages are not self-executing; they have to be executed by a SQL Server that has the Integration Service installed and running.

It is not possible to put an SSIS package on your file system and run it from C# code without the Integration Services software on the machine.